# difference when defining array under Linux or Windows

Tags: c++

Here is a simple code of defining an array. I noticed this code will work(compile and run) under Linux(OpenSue,gcc compiler), but it will not work under Windows system. The compiler gave error prompt. Does anybody know the reason? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N;
    cin>>N;
    int ar[N];
    ar[0]=0;
    cout<<"ar[0]= "<<ar[0]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Define "work" vs. "not work"...

Comment: What compiler are you using in Windows?

Comment: As the error you quoted says, you didn't sacrifice the right kind of goat.

Comment: How could this possibly work under GCC?  I didn't think that GCC was that big of a pile.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code isn’t valid C++ since C++ does not allow declaring a (stack-allocated) array with a variable size as you do. The reason for this is that C++ offers better mechanisms of declaring dynamically sized arrays, using the `std::vector` class from its standard library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    vector<int> ar(N);
    ar[0] = 0;
    cout << "ar[0] = " << ar[0] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`g++` (the compiler you used on Linux) by default allows this through a compiler extension.

Comment: Yes, the code can be compiled and run and give right result. So you think gcc compiler is the reason?

Comment: @Jackie When compiling with gcc, use the option `-ansi -pedantic` to avoid surprises like this. And add `-Wall -Wextra` for good practice.

Comment: Works in GCC because it's a valid construct in the newer C standard.  GCC doesn't make clear distinctions between the two languages unless you ask it to.

Comment: Note that the reason why variable size arrays are not allowed in C++ is that the size is part of the type, and if they were allowed then the exact type of a variable would be unknown at compile time. Think on what happens if you pass a variable sized array to `template <typename T, int N> void foo( T (&a)[N] );`. The size of the array while calling that template is required at compile time (to produce a particular instantiation), but with variable sized arrays it is only known at runtime. That C++ offers other containers is not a reason not to offer this feature.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a difference between Linux and Windows per se. It's a difference between gcc and MS VC++.

This type of code is legal and allowed in C (as of C99). It's not, however, allowed in C++ --  but gcc provides it as an extension in C++ anyway. In this particular respect, MS VC++ attempts to follow the (C++) standard more closely, and does not provide this particular extension.

If you run gcc on Windows, however, (e.g., [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)) you'll get the same behavior on Windows that you're currently observing on Linux.

As @Konrad Rudolph already pointed out, the right way to handle this under C++ is almost certainly to switch from using an array to using a vector instead.

Answer (score 1):

Variable-length arrays (e.g. `int ar[N];`) are not permitted in C++, but GCC can do them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

not sure why it compiles in linux, but you can't declare int ar[N] on the stack like that.